# How to make inner div opacity 1 in CSS?

Tags: css, opacity

I am trying to achieve inner div opacity 1 while its parent div opacity in 0.5.
Please find my codepen link

https://codepen.io/SandeshSardar/pen/moVyEy

As per current result inner div to getting opacity 0.5 even after applying opacity 1.

```
<div class="container">
<div  class="image">
  <div class="green" >
    <p>this div also should take opacity </p>
    </div>
    <div class="middle">

    </div>
</div>
```

```
    .container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.image {
position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
   background: red;
    height: 150px;
  width: 500px;
}

.middle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.container .image {
   background: rgba(255,0,0,.3);

}

.container .middle {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.container .green {
 position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
   background: green;
    height: 50px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the parent .image with

```
background:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
```

and the child .middle with

```
background:rgba(0,0,255,1);
```

The 4th value of rgba is the opacity!

EDIT:

```
.container .green {
 position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
   background: rgba(0,255,0,1);
    height: 50px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

If you want the opacity of .green to be 0.1 change it to rgba(0,255,0,0.1) instead of opacity: 0.1

Comment: it's not really an inheritance

Comment: Yes, the .middle's opacity multiplies the .container's opacity. It's not an inheritance, it's more like a max range (100% inner opacity = 1*outer opacity = 1*0.5 = 0.5).

Comment: Please remove duplicate, i have updated my codepen and question

Comment: @user7423463 check my update and use rgba instead of opacity